# C++. Could anyone help me find error in my code for solving equation with simple iterations method? i getting solution like -1.#IND00

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the next equation with C++ help: 3sin(sqrt(x)) + 0.35x - 3.8 = 0
The area with solution is [2, 3]
I wrote next code:

```
float f(float x)
{
    return (3 * sin(sqrt(x))) + (0.35 * x) - 3.8; //this is equation i am trying to solve
}

float g(float x, float(*f_ptr)(float)) 
{
    const float CONST = 0.1f; //const used to solve equation

    return CONST * f_ptr(x) + x;
}

void Task4_CalculateSomething()
{
    float x0, //starting aproximation
        xk, //current aproximation
        a = 2, //left barrier
        b = 3, //right barrier
        epsilon = 0.001; //allowed error

    const float REAL_SOLUTION = 2.2985; //real solution of selected equation

    printf("Setup starting aproximation: ");
    scanf("%f", &x0);

    do
    {
        xk = g(x0, f); //calc current aproximation

        if (fabs(xk - x0) < epsilon) //if Xn - Xn-1 fits the allowed error, the solution must be found
            break; //then we exit
        else
            x0 = xk; //else reset x values
    }
    while (fabs(a - x0) > epsilon && fabs(b - x0) > epsilon);

    printf("Found solution: %f\nReal solution: %f\n", xk, REAL_SOLUTION);
}
```

But it gives me weird results like -1.#IND00 which i don't even know what is it.
And i can't find any error there...

Comment: What is `g` all about? As for `-1.#IND00`, that's just a NaN.

Comment: let me find some english description of simple iterations method, so i will try to explain you. the things i read was in russian

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: problem solved then, non?

Comment: To solve the equation F(x) = 0, we can express it by equal equation x = f(x), but same equation we can get by multiplying left and right part of equation by CONSTANT like that: x = CONST * F(x) + x. That what was g all about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another algorithm like this:

1. Write the derivative of the function: der=1.5*cos(sqrt((x))/sqrt(x)+.35
2. next value is xk=x0-mysinc(x0)/der(x0)

in few steps will fall into the solution... or make your variable CONST have a dynamic value of -1/der(x).

Comment: thank you very much! But can you tell me where did that magic values come from? and what mean +.35 in first step?

Comment: @Kosmos: Newton's Method to solve F(x)=0   [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)    Derivative function of: 3sin(sqrt(x)) + 0.35x - 3.8   is    1.5*cos(sqrt((x))/sqrt(x)+.35  (derivative function of 0,35*x is 0.35).  The derivative function in one point calculates the slope of the curve. If you take the line that crosses that point and has the same slope, cuts the horizontal axe near the zero of the original function.

Comment: thanks for explaining me this all, i think i will choose the second method you suggested about dynamic CONST. also, i forgot to ask, what is mysinc in second step?

Comment: @Kosmos: sorry, mysinc is a typing error :D I meant your real function "f". So xk=x0-f(x0)/der(x0)

Comment: got it all. you are great to help me solve this things after much time passed :D

Comment: Yes, Newton's method is how to do this. I assumed that there was some reason, i.e. the homework assignment specified it, behind the algorithm in the original code. That's why it never occurred to me to suggest using plain Newton. I just thought you had to use whatever method you were originally trying to implement.

Comment: actually... i though @chasques just suggested me how to avoid xk going negative by changing calculations, but i hoped it still would be simple iterations method, and now i am totally lost :D Somehow mathematics guys should be able to solve this equations without xk going negative, but my algorithm can't? what peoples do if xk going negative when calculating by head?

Comment: Yeah, Newton's method can be troublesome. Since you have the root bracketed, I would use bisection. I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: "f" is a "very nice" function, not too strange in [2 3] you suggested so x0 will not be <0 with Newton's in any initial value (not tested it, but almost 90% sure). Newton's is not too complex, and bisections is easier ... but you'll need more iterations (average). Evaluate fast and "no-so-complex" with easier but slower. Be careful!! not all iterative algorithms converge to a solution (not even Newton's), but as I said, "f" is a nice function

Comment: @Kosmos There's very little simpler than bisection. It will solve that equation instantly. It's a simpler approach than Newton's method in a number of ways.

Comment: maybe this is all right, but task specifies to use simple iterations :( That's why i need to know what peoples do if xk goes negative while they calculating in head. Most likely i need to add some checks in my algorithm, but i don't know what to do if xk negative :D

Answer (score 3):

At a high level, what is happening is that:

1. Your algorithm doesn't work correctly.
2. At a certain iteration, `xk` becomes negative.
3. When that is passed to `sqrt`, a NaN is returned.
4. The iteration terminates.
5. The call to `printf` displays the `NaN` as `-1.#IND00`.

You can discern all this with a debugger, or even with the old fashioned technique of throwing in some debug `printf` output. For example, add some code to print `xk` on each iteration of the loop.

Since you have knowledge that the solution lies in [2,3], I would personally use a bracketing root finder. For example, [bisection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Comment: @Kosmos It's easy to get code wrong. The big thing to learn is how to diagnose it. If you had seen various intermediate values then you would have immediately seen what was going on yourself. Don't try to program with a blindfold on! Good luck! ;-)